# We should rename [outsourcing] to something more easily discoverable

Tags: feature-request, retag-request, meta

Right now we are using [outsourcing](/questions/tagged/outsourcing) for questions relating to other companies using Stack Overflow as a support channel for their API.

The thing is, "outsourcing" by itself doesn't seem particularly descriptive. While "outsourcing support to Stack Overflow" is a phrase that comes up a fair bit in the meta posts we've made on the subject, it's not a natural thing that comes to mind if I think about asking a question on this topic as someone who's not necessarily well-versed in the meta lore and history here.

The tag wiki helps, sure, but how about a more specific tag? For example, `[third-party-support]`? `[outsourcing-support]`? `[company-support]`?

Comment: Does it really mean "We are handing off our support to Stack Overflow" (in the vein of the current crop of "reach out to [Company Name]" meta questions, in which case [outsourcing-support] fits perfectly), or does it mean something else?

Comment: Perhaps outsourced-support?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The tag wiki says "For questions relating to companies and products outside Stack Overflow using a Stack Overflow site as a support forum or similar.", so it looks like it means "we are handing off our support to SO".